# How to generate a core file for a crashed app in XCode + gdb?

Tags: xcode, gdb

Having reproduced an elusive bug that crashes my app (running inside the iOS simulator, to be precise), I want to generate a core file for inspection later. On Linux I would run generate-core-file from within gdb, but that command isn't available in the Mac OS X version of gdb.

So, how can I generate a core file from within gdb? There are ways to ask the OS for a core dump of a crashed app, but I fear the app will change some of its state by then. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunate there is no gcore command in mac osx gdb, but there is a good article about how to generate core dump on osx

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103164014/https://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter8/core/)

In this article there is a downloadable source code to generate core dump, which I have used many times.